# Issue with stripe's python sdk's PaymentMethod

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use Stripe's PaymentMethod object to fetch a users saved credit cards and am getting an error "'module' object has no attribute 'PaymentMethod'" on print(stripe.PaymentMethod) (but not on, for example, print(stripe.Charge)).

Stripe has stripe.PaymentMethod listed on their API docs - does it not actually work?

Example code from the api docs that I was trying to replicate:

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc"

stripe.PaymentMethod.create(
  type='card',
  card={
    'number': '4242424242424242',
    'exp_month': 12,
    'exp_year': 2020,
    'cvc': '123',
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

pip install --upgrade stripe fixed my problem.

Looks like my version was just old.

Comment: What was your old version?